# How does one search a picture online?

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

If one has a picture file, like `.jpg`, how does one search (maybe Google) if this picture is around online?

Comment: search online for "reverse image search"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to **https://www.google.sk/imghp?**
- click on a camera to upload your picture
- select **Upload an image**
- press **<kbd>Choose file</kbd>** button

[image: 5]

Answer (score 0):

One answer here already mentions Google Image Search. In my experience, when I wanted to find pages with similar images e.g. to identify what is in the image (e.g. a bird, a plant, a logo) I had much more success with Yandex image search, AKA [Яндекс.Картинки](https://yandex.com/images/).

I don't know whether its UI is localized to other languages than Russian, but I think image search doesn't rely much on text :)

To use it, choose the "aim" button marked in red in this screenshot:

[image]

Then drag an image into the "Перетащите изображение сюда" box:

[image]

Or you can enter image URL into the "Введите адрес изображения" field, or browse your filesystem for the file by clicking the "Выбрать файл" button, or paste from the clipboard by the "Вставить из буфера" button.

After this the search starts automatically (for URL entry click the "Найти" button to the right of the text field to start the search).